# how to use feather icons in a select dropdown

Tags: html, layout, icons

I'm using [feather](https://github.com/feathericons/feather) icons.

How to use a feather icon on `<option>` tag?

I'm using the icons like this normally

```html
<span data-feather="calendar"></span>
```

```js
feather.replace()
```

But in an option tag feather icons are not being displayed

```html
<option>
    <span data-feather="calendar"></span>
    This Week
</option>
```

[image: sample]

The `<span>` is getting removed in the browser.

How do I display the feather icons in a select dropdown?

Answer (score -1):

You have to call the `feather.replace()` method:

```
<script>
  feather.replace()
</script>
```

All elements that have a data-feather attribute will be replaced with SVG markup corresponding to their data-feather attribute value.

See the [API Reference](https://github.com/punker76/feather#api-reference) for more information about feather.replace().

Comment: I already did it. Look at the question I have `feather.replace()` in the question

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the feather.replace() at the end of the js file.